# Brightness control of an image using opencv in android

Tags: opencv, face-detection, brightness, android

I may do some actions like face detection and skin color detection in android using opencv. However,human skin color may be affected by many factors like the angle of light when we capture the photo. How can I do the brightness optimisation so the skin color detection result will be closer to the user's skin color??
Please give me some helps. Thank You